# Is there any way to multiple deployment UWP to RaspPi2

Tags: deployment, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I want to deploy my universal windows application to raspberry pi 2 devices. I can do that one by one. But how can I deploy multiple pi devices at once?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio needs a dedicated target (your phone, computer, PI, etc.) to deploy/debug your app.
It can handle only 1 target so you won't be able to do it using Visual Studio.

What you can try (I'm not 100% it will work): create a post build event that call a .bat/.ps1 file which will do the deployment.
To do so, you just need to be sure that there is a command line that exists to deploy the package "manually".

Answer (score 0):

One thing is you can deploy an app via the web portal. If you connect multiple RPi2 on the same network you may write a script to deploy the app through the web interface.

[image]